# Can't repair structures when attacking enemy stronghold

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war

So infurating! When playing Dawn of War: Dark Crusade as the Space Marines, I can't repair my structures with servitors. The servitors go up to the structure, the repair animation plays but the structure's HP does not go up an inch.

Like I say, it works fine when playing normal maps... just when I go up against a stronghold I can't repair my structures!

Is this a known glitch? Really irritating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mod/patch:

http://www.gamefront.com/files/files/23145178/dow_dark_crusade_bugfix_mod_v26.zip

fixes it. If the link goes dark the filename is dow_dark_crusade_[...]x_mod_v26.zip

By a guy called Soul Reaver.